# What is the reason of not executing all of the threads in an unbounded threadpool executer

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor, java-threads

I am using an ExecutorService 
`ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20000);` 
And I have in the `ThreadSystem.java` class two static members:

```
public static Integer count = 0;
public static Integer rejectedCount = 0;
```

then I'm adding threads to it:

```
for (i = 0; i < 20001; i++) {
    Runnable worker = new MyThread();
    try {
        executor.execute(worker);
    } catch (RejectedExecutionException ex) {
        rejectedCount++;
    }
}
executor.shutdown();
while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
}
```

Inside the thread:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    ThreadSystem.count++;
    try{   
        Thread.sleep(50);       
    }
    catch(InterruptedException ex){
        Logger.getLogger(MyThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(),ex);
      }
}
```

The results I'm getting indicate that there are threads that are not executed and the `count` variable is not equal to the number of threads created, although the `rejectedCount` that refers to the rejected threads is 0:

> count:19488 
>  rejected count: 0

So what else can assure me that all of the threads will run, and what is the reason of that case: **the count(runnable threads) is not equal to the added threads**?

Comment: The operation you are performing isn't thread safe so you should expect it to missing some increments. Try using an `AtomicInteger` with `incrementAndGet();`

Comment: Your code is a perfect example of race condition. Value of a static counter is not equal to number of submitted tasks only because of race condition happened due to lack of synchronization.

Answer (score 6):

Your code is the "perfect example" of a race-condition: Your access to

```
 public static Integer count = 0;
```

is not synchronized, so several threads may do this line at the same time:

```
 ThreadSystem.count++;
```

This can/may result in writes being lost, because several threads may at the same time do the equivalent of `ThreadSystem.count = ThreadSystem.count + 1` , and some will read the old and not-yet updated number for the operation.

Either use appropriate `synchronized` guards or use something along [`AtomicInteger#incrementAndGet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#incrementAndGet) for the counter.

Note, that you *must not* synchronize on the `count` in this case, since `Integer` is an immutable object and operations on boxed primitives (`int` to `Integer`, `long` to `Long`, ...) are basically assignments to the variable. Using `AtomicInteger` is the best solution for this given problem.

<s>The same is true for your `rejectedCount`.</s> (Not true, since this is updated only by one thread.)

Comment: I assume `rejectedCount` is only updated by one thread (though not at all in this case)

Comment: BTW a `synchronized(count) { count++; }` *wouldn't* be appropriate. ;)